# How do I correctly receive a signal using a signal analyzer?

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection

For the past few weeks, I have been trying to send a Zaddof Chu signal using a vector signal generator, and receive it using a signal analyzer. Both devices are made by R&S.

However, the signal I receive is extremely distorted even at very high SNR's. I would really appreciate any hints at where the issue could be originating from.

Here is a the I and Q signals of the 21 samples ZC sequence, upsampled by 8 transmitted at $10\textrm{ kHz}$ base bandwidth and $2.4\textrm{ GHz}$ carrier frequency.

- I signal: 
  [image]
- Q signal: 
  [image]

And here is the received signal sampled at $1.6\textrm{ MHz}$.

Received I signal:
 [image]

Received Q signal:
 [image]

**EDIT:**

After using the same clock for both devices, and using a coaxial cable to connect them both, I was able to receive an almost perfect real part, but the imaginary part is very distorted.

Comment: You might be best off contacting the support staff for your equipment, but what power level are you using? Perhaps you're getting some amplifier saturation or ADC clipping.

Comment: I just tried to reduce the amplitude, but the output was similar.

Comment: how do you generate your signals? are you using the customized modulation or the ARB waveform?

Comment: I am using the ARB waveform. I generate the signal using matlab, then I convert it using R&S ARB Toolbox PLUS, and load it using a USB on the signal generator which forwards the I and Q streams to another signal generator that up converts the signal to the RF frequency.